# Is there a programming language named "Ç"?

Tags: programming-languages

I recently reviewed a résumé for a candidate who claimed to have skills in both "C" and "Ç". Since I'm generally interested in programming languages, I was curious to learn more about this c-cedilla language, but after much searching, I can't find any evidence that it exists. I searched wikipedia for a disambiguation page, I searched Google, I searched http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/. I searched Google again, with a variety of advanced search options. I searched https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/grammars.yml. I searched https://stackoverflow.com/tags.

None of the places I've searched thus far have given me any reason to believe this language exists.

Does there exist a programming language named "Ç"? If not, is there another kind of technical tool by that name?

Comment: Perhaps they meant C# (and weren't sure how to express the "sharp")???

Comment: Maybe a misspelling of C++ or C#? With an international keyboard pressing the wrong button (like `Alt Gr` instead of `Shift`) could easily create such a character.

Comment: "C-dilla"? Clever name for a language…

Comment: On Android's Google Keyboard, a long press on C produces Ç, and on Mac OS X (since Lion), a long press on C produces a popup menu with Ç as the first item.

Comment: @deceze Obviously the language of choice for implementing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dillo

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not think there is. Probably a typo - but if this interests you that much, you can reach out and ask him...

Comment: "reach out and ask him" - that's actually quite a good idea. Might even suggest for him to open a stack-overflow account and answer this question right here.

Answer (score 0):

Afte checking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages. I Don't think so. It could be Caché ObjectScript language or a self-written language. The best way to make sure of it by inviting the candidate to interview or by calling him.